# Issue with product search in Shopware 6.4.13.0

Tags: shopware, shopware6

the product search doesn't seem to work as expected. Products are obviously supposed to be searchable by their product number according to the search settings in the backend. But when I search by product number there are no results. I tried to set the ranking to a higher number than 1000, but also no success.

A possible workaround would be to add a product number to the search keyword field, which actually works. But this is not really a good solution considering that the shop contains thousands of products.

Is there something I might have missed in the system settings? Or does the search function probably have a problem with product numbers with dashes (example: 99-670-846-0)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share more details. How is this problem related to programming itself? Did you code anything to extend Shopware's own search algorithm? Then please share your code. Otherwise (if you are solely using their code without any own extension) this question is off-topic here

Comment: This might be a problem with indexation. You should check the database table `product_search_keyword`. If it is empty, or the product number you're searching for is not there, you might have to run the product indexer